# Open current Finder folder in Terminal by shortcut in Snow Leopard

Tags: finder, terminal.app

I want to use some shortcut in Finder to open current folder in Terminal. I've only found an application, that adds icon to Finder's toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an application that does this in my finder toolbar. I use [Open Terminal Here](http://www.entropy.ch/software/applescript/) but that site also suggests [ShellHere](http://www.etresoft.org/shellhere.html). Note that those are just AppleScripts that launch Terminal and CD to the directory found by examining the front-most Finder window. Nothing says those apps have to be in your Finder toolbar, and nothing is stopping you from assigning a global keyboard shortcut to run those apps as they reside elsewhere. Would that solve your question?

Answer (score -2):

in a terminal, just type: 'open xxxx' where xxxx is the folder you want, and it'll automatically open finder.

run 'open' to see options or 'man open' for manual